# Replace values in a dfm sparse matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I'm using the quanteda package to produce a sparse matrix of word frequency counts. I want to make a change so that the output is bonary so simply 1 or 0, is the word present or not but i'm not sure how to do this with a sparse matrix.

```
install.packages(quanteda)
```

Example matrix

```
trainingset <- as.dfm(matrix(c(1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                    0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                    0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                    0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
                  ncol=6, nrow=5, byrow=TRUE,
                  dimnames = list(docs = paste("d", 1:5, sep = ""),
                                  features = c("Beijing", "Chinese",  "Japan", "Macao", 
                                               "Shanghai", "Tokyo"))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at `str(trainingset)` you can see the slots of the matrix. As with sparse matrices the `x` slot holds the data, so you can change this to binary using

```
trainingset@x <- as.numeric(trainingset@x > 0)

Document-feature matrix of: 5 documents, 6 features (60% sparse).
5 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
    features
docs Beijing Chinese Japan Macao Shanghai Tokyo
  d1       1       1     0     0        0     0
  d2       0       1     0     0        1     0
  d3       0       1     0     1        0     0
  d4       0       1     1     0        0     1
  d5       0       1     1     0        0     1
```